# Connect 4 check for win isn't working - how do I fix?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

EDIT: The instructions were really confusing for me.

"Step Seven: findSpotForCol and endGame
Right now, the game drops always drops a piece to the top of the column, even if a piece is already there. Fix this function so that it finds the lowest empty spot in the game board and returns the y coordinate (or null if the column is filled)."

This makes me think that findSpotForCol is supposed to put where each piece goes, however step 5 says:
"While not everything will work, you should now be able to click on a column and see a piece appear at the very bottom of that column."

So the piece should already be at the bottom on step 5, not waiting til step 7?

```
*****
```

I am doing an assignment creating a connect 4 game. There was some code already, and instructions on how to complete the rest. I, uh, don't think I followed the instructions to a "t" (as in certain code should go inside a certain function), but it all works as intended (mostly).

Every click is a different turn(changing the piece colors). Pieces stack how they're supposed to. If the board is completely full (as in tie), the game ends. Basically everything works in the game except for "ending the game" when 4 of the same pieces match.

The code for checking the win had already been written by my instructor. Is anyone able to check my code and advise how the check for win should be written for the code I have? I've spent quite a few hours on this, and rather not start over to write code that works for the check-for-win function pre-set by my instructor.

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Connect 4</title>
  <link href="connect4.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<div id="game">
  <table id="board"></table>
</div>

<script src="connect4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* game board table */

#board td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: solid 1px #666;
}

/* pieces are div within game table cells: draw as colored circles */

.piece {
    /* TODO: make into circles */
    margin: 5px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

/* TODO: make pieces red/blue,  depending on player 1/2 piece */
.plyr1 {
    background-color: blue;
}

.plyr2 {
    background-color: red;
}

/* column-top is table row of clickable areas for each column */

#column-top td {
    border: dashed 1px lightgray;
}

#column-top td:hover {
    background-color: gold;
}
```

JS

```
/** Connect Four
 *
 * Player 1 and 2 alternate turns. On each turn, a piece is dropped down a
 * column until a player gets four-in-a-row (horiz, vert, or diag) or until
 * board fills (tie)
 */

const WIDTH = 7;
const HEIGHT = 6;

let currPlayer = 1; // active player: 1 or 2
const board = []; // array of rows, each row is array of cells  (board[y][x])

/** makeBoard: create in-JS board structure:
 *    board = array of rows, each row is array of cells  (board[y][x])
 */

function makeBoard() {
    let board2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        board2.push(null);
        for (let j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            board[i] = board2;
        }
    }
}

/** makeHtmlBoard: make HTML table and row of column tops. */

function makeHtmlBoard() {
    const htmlBoard = document.querySelector('#board'); //selecting the board

    const top = document.createElement('tr'); //creating a table row element
    top.setAttribute('id', 'column-top'); //setting id of tr just created
    top.addEventListener('click', handleClick); // adding an event listener that listens for handleClick( function)

    for (let x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        const headCell = document.createElement('td'); //creating a table data element equal to WIDTH
        headCell.setAttribute('id', x); //setting id of td just created to x
        top.append(headCell); //displaying headingCell right under where top is displayed (nesting the td inside of the tr)
    }
    htmlBoard.append(top); //displaying top right under where htmlBoard is displayed

    for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        const row = document.createElement('tr'); //creating a table row element * HEIGHT
        for (let x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            const cell = document.createElement('td'); //creating a table data element equal to WIDTH
            cell.setAttribute('id', `${y}-${x}`); //setting id of td just created
            row.append(cell); //displaying cell right under where row is displayed (nesting each td inside of each tr)
        }
        htmlBoard.append(row); //displaying row right under where htmlBoard is displayed
    }
}

/** findSpotForCol: given column x, return top empty y (null if filled) */

function findSpotForCol(x) {
    // TODO: write the real version of this, rather than always returning 0
    return 0;
}

/** placeInTable: update DOM to place piece into HTML table of board */

function placeInTable(y, x) {
    // TODO: make a div and insert into correct table cell

    const div = document.createElement('div');

    div.classList.add('piece');
    const top = document.querySelector(`[id='0-${x}']`);
    if (currPlayer === 1 && top.innerHTML === '') {
        div.classList.add('plyr1');
        currPlayer = 2;
    } else if (currPlayer === 2 && top.innerHTML === '') {
        div.classList.add('plyr2');
        currPlayer = 1;
    }

    let arrHeight = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        arrHeight.push(i);
    }

    for (i of arrHeight.reverse()) {
        if (document.getElementById(`${i}-${x}`).innerHTML === '') {
            const selected = document.getElementById(`${i}-${x}`);
            const top = document.getElementById(`6 -${x}`);
            return selected.append(div);
        }
    }
}

/** endGame: announce game end */

function endGame(msg) {
    // TODO: pop up alert message
    alert('Test');
}

/** handleClick: handle click of column top to play piece */

function handleClick(evt) {
    // get x from ID of clicked cell
    let x = +evt.target.id;

    // get next spot in column (if none, ignore click)
    let y = findSpotForCol(x);
    if (y === null) {
        return;
    }

    // place piece in board and add to HTML table
    // TODO: add line to update in-memory board
    placeInTable(y, x);

    // check for win
    if (checkForWin()) {
        return endGame(`Player ${currPlayer} won!`);
    }

    // check for tie
    // TODO: check if all cells in board are filled; if so call, call endGame
    const tie = document.querySelectorAll('td');
    const tieArr = [ ...tie ];
    tieArr.reverse();
    for (let i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
        tieArr.pop();
    }

    let tie42 = tieArr.filter((v) => {
        return v.innerHTML !== '';
    });

    if (tie42.length === 42) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            endGame();
        }, 1);
    }
}

/** checkForWin: check board cell-by-cell for "does a win start here?" */

function checkForWin() {
    function _win(cells) {
        // Check four cells to see if they're all color of current player
        //  - cells: list of four (y, x) cells
        //  - returns true if all are legal coordinates & all match currPlayer
        return cells.every(([ y, x ]) => y >= 0 && y < HEIGHT && x >= 0 && x < WIDTH && board[y][x] === currPlayer);
    }

    // TODO: read and understand this code. Add comments to help you.

    for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
            let horiz = [ [ y, x ], [ y, x + 1 ], [ y, x + 2 ], [ y, x + 3 ] ];
            let vert = [ [ y, x ], [ y + 1, x ], [ y + 2, x ], [ y + 3, x ] ];
            let diagDR = [ [ y, x ], [ y + 1, x + 1 ], [ y + 2, x + 2 ], [ y + 3, x + 3 ] ];
            let diagDL = [ [ y, x ], [ y + 1, x - 1 ], [ y + 2, x - 2 ], [ y + 3, x - 3 ] ];

            if (_win(horiz) || _win(vert) || _win(diagDR) || _win(diagDL)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

makeBoard();
makeHtmlBoard();
```

Comment: How can you expect it to work when you have not implemented those essential TODO?

Comment: Concerning the new question you added at the top: yes, you would see the discs dropped at the *bottom* once you implemented up to step 5, but not higher than the *bottom* (you worked around that by inspecting the HTML document), and therefore it would not be enough to detect a win. For that to work you really need to complete the other steps (I don't know the other steps, but at least 7 is needed for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few essential things you did not code:

```
// TODO: add line to update in-memory board
// TODO: write the real version of this, rather than always returning 0
```

Without those implementations you cannot expect the 4-in-a-row detection to work.

But let's take the issues one by one, starting at the top:

(1) The way you create the board is wrong: it only creates *one* `board2` array, and so all the entries of `board` are referencing the *same* array. Whatever happens to it will be the same whether you look at it via `board[0]`, `board[1]`, or whichever entry... Here is how you could do it correctly:

```
function makeBoard() {
    for (let i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        board[i] = Array(WIDTH).fill(null); // create a new array each time!
    }
}
```

(2) The function `findSpotForCol` always returns 0, which of course is wrong. It is a pity you did not attempt to complete this function. The purpose of such assignments is that you work on them, and learn as you try.

It could look like this:

```
function findSpotForCol(x) {
    for (let y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        if (board[y][x] === null) return y;
    }
    return null;
}
```

(3) `placeInTable` should not change `currPlayer`. It is not its job to do so. Changing it here will give it the wrong value at the time you call `checkForWin`. Instead you should modify `currPlayer` as the last thing you do in `handleClick`, and it can be simply this line:

```
currPlayer = 3 - currPlayer;
```

(3b) `placeInTable` is overly complicated. Although it works fine, I would write it like below, making use of the `rows` and `cells` methods; no need for HTML `id` attributes, except for the `id` of the table element.

```
function placeInTable(y, x) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.classList.add('piece', 'plyr' + currPlayer);
    document.querySelector("#board").rows[HEIGHT - y].cells[x].append(div);
}
```

(4) The `endGame` shows "Test", which is not its purpose. Again, you should have updated that code. It should alert this:

```
alert(msg);
```

(5) In `handleClick` you did not do anything to modify the `board`. You should add this line just before the call to `placeInTable`:

```
board[y][x] = currPlayer;
```

(6) The check for a tie should not be based on what is in the document, but on what is in memory. A move counter would make it easier, but let's just do it by scanning `board`. You should of course pass an argument to `endGame`:

```
if (board.every(row => row.every(Boolean))) {
    return endGame("It's a draw!");
}
```

Note the use of  `Boolean` here. It is the callback function given to `every`, and will return `false` when it is given `null`, `true` when it is given 1 or 2.

With these adaptations it should work.

Comment: I'm still going through each part of what you have, I just want to mention that I didn't complete findSpotForCol because the instructions said (before even getting to findSpotForCol) that the placeInTable should place the piece at the bottom of each column, so I placed the code in placeInTable. Instructions were conflicting in my opinion

Comment: Also, for the endGame I know I didn't complete it. I added the test to see if it worked. Thats why its called "test"

Answer (score 0):

Just judging from a quick glance on your code: There is an in-memory table called `board`, which the check for a win is using. However, your `placeInTable` implementation does not update this table, but directly inserts DOM-elements.

What I would advise you to do instead, is to sepearte the model (the state of the game) from the visualization. When you get the click-event, you update the in-memory table, then you visualize the entire table, e.g. by setting the appropriate css-classes in the already created html-table.
Then you check for a win.

Also, the check for winning compares against a variable called `test`, which does not seem to be defined anywhere.

Comment: I changed that when I was trying to figure it out. Test is supposed to be currPlayer. The instructions for placeInTable were: "This function should add a div inside the correct td cell in the HTML game board. This div should have the piece class on it, and should have a class for whether the current player is 1 or 2, like p1 or p2."